# Retrieving weapons from storage

Tags: far-cry-4

Ok I know to go to the store to swap weapons in wheel, but I cannot re-equip the bow.
Don't see it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am playing right now on PS4, and here is where I see it:

1. Go to a trading post.
2. Pick the middle option "Buy & Customize"
3. Move over to "Weapons" tab (R1 on PS4 to move).
4. Now scroll down in this set of weapons (using direction pad for PS4).

The Hunter Bow and/or Recurve bow are probably just off screen from the starting point of the selection screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how exactly do you know he wants help with the PS4 version?

Comment: I don't.  Just letting it be known that that was the system I was using when I did it (think of it as a disclaimer haha).

Comment: Yea I figured it out, I had a senior gamer moment. I didn't scroll down in the main weapons menu. Thanx for the response.